# How to rate CVSS when PR is low but UI of admin user is required

Tags: cvss

I have a situation where an attacker with low privileges can perform an attack. However, in order to complete the attack, the system has to be restarted, which can only be done by the admin account.

In this case , the  UI is required. But I am confused with PR value. Should I rate it as low or high?

Comment: "An attack" is quite limited information. It's better to provide details about the attack. In case a reboot is required in order to enable the attack or payload (as you suggested), the PR value should be high in my opinion.

Comment: Are you sure only an admin can do it? An attacker can't e.g. DoS the system to trigger an automatic restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That a low. From the [spec](https://www.first.org/cvss/specification-document) re Privileges Required:

> This metric describes the level of privileges an attacker must possess before successfully exploiting the vulnerability.

Emphasis on the attacker's privileges, not anyone else's.

However, you should also indicate that user interaction is required.